# How to test code with asynchronous test execution using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I just learnt how `clock.tick()` works under the hood and I can't figure out one thing. If your test execution is synchronous up to the point `setTimeout` is called, jasmine "moves it in time" for you and executes, you're OK, but what if you're doing integration testing and `setTimeout`s are called asynchronously by browser/phantomJS? For instance websocket connection opening sometime in future invokes `setTimeout`, then test is long over before first `setTimeout` is even called. Such an asynchronous code cannot be tested using clock.tick(), right ?

Comment: They cover this right in their docs, for both 1.3 an 2.0. [Read the docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support)

Comment: No, that's pretty much the same as `clock.tick()`, notice that they call `setTimeout()` in the first `runs()`, that's just synchronous test execution, I'm talking about situation when setTimeout() is called asynchronously by a third party (IO/browser/phantomJS)... If you don't call set the `flag` via `setTimeout` in the first `runs()` but it is set asynchronously, it won't work, the last `runs()` is not even invoked

Comment: Imho unless the first `runs()` directly invokes `setTimeout` the whole thing just won't work. You know what I have in the first `runs()`? Imagine just `new Websocket` where `ws.onOpen` asynchronously either sets the `flag` or invokes some `setTimeout()`, but at that time the `runs()` is long over ...